# Google Cloud Shell doesn't login

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

If I am trying to open Cloud Shell, I see the message:

> Your Cloud Shell session closed before the initial prompt displayed, which can mean there is a problem with your ~/.bashrc file or ~/.tmux.conf file.

I logged in as root (safe mode) and deleted my user & the home directory, then restart Cloud Shell. My user was created from a skeleton, but I got the same message.

If disable tmux in terminall settings, will be added messege:

> bash: [[: /etc/profile.d/customize_environment.sh: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/etc/profile.d/customize_environment.sh")
> but Shell doesn't work.

File customize_environment.sh is the same as it on another google account.

How fix it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried to follow the documentation [Resetting Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/resetting-cloud-shell#resetting)?

Comment: In my initial message is wrote that Shell Reset was done.
> I logged in as root (safe mode) and deleted my user & the home directory, then restart Cloud Shell.

Comment: Could you update your question with the actions you did that cause this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Go into safe/root mode, navigate into your $HOME directory (/home/{user}) and move/remove your .customize_environment file. This worked for me. I don't know about you, but my script hasn't been working these past few days. Maybe Google changed something and this crashes our .customize_environment script.

Maybe this will work for you too.

(You can create the script again after everything is normalized and it shouldn't crash a second time, but double check it)

Answer (score 0):

remove `/home/{user}/.customize_environment` file, but be aware that if you run `rm $HOME/.customize_environment`, you wull get `no such file`.
that's because you are trying to delete another file for anotjer youser i.e: `/home/root`.

if you forgot your user name rum `ls /home` first.